# The installed version of Bison, /c/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/bison, is too old to use with PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, rdbms, bison, configure

I am trying to run PostgreSQL in my windows laptop using its source code by cloning its repo from Github.
For this I am following this [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/install-make.html)
But while trying to run `./configure` command I am encountering this error

```
configure: error:
*** The installed version of Bison, /c/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/bison, is too old to use with PostgreSQL.
*** Bison version 2.3 or later is required, but this is .
```

Although I have checked version of bison in my pc using

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin> bison --version
bison (GNU Bison) 2.4.1
Written by Robert Corbett and Richard Stallman.

Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO 
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I have added bison in the user `PATH` variable too.
Now I don't know why its complaining to have lower version than 2.3!

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Please do not ask new questions in comments. Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question in a post. But a post should not be edited to an essentially different question or to invalidate reasonable posted answers. Code questions require a [mre]. Installation questions are generally off-topic. They may be on-topic at another Stack Exchange site. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bug with GnuWin32 and Bison. Per the Postgres docs here [Install Windows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/install-windows-full.html#INSTALL-WINDOWS-FULL-REQUIREMENTS):

> Note

> The Bison distribution from GnuWin32 appears to have a bug that causes Bison to malfunction when installed in a directory with spaces in the name, such as the default location on English installations C:\Program Files\GnuWin32. Consider installing into C:\GnuWin32 or use the NTFS short name path to GnuWin32 in your PATH environment setting (e.g., C:\PROGRA~1\GnuWin32).